# decorator and method_exists

Tags: php

I have the following code; what should be added to the decorator class to pass the check of `method_exists()`? In real task I can't change the function that calls `method_exists()`.
Also any idea how to cheat 'get_class_methods()' and  'get_class_vars()'?

```
class real {
    function __construct($arg1,$arg2)
    {

    }

    function test()
    {
        echo "test output\n";
    }
}

class decorator
{
    protected $real;

    function __construct()
    {
        eval('$this->real=new real('.implode(',',func_get_args()).');');
    }

    function __call($method,$args)
    {
        echo "called $method\n";
        $ret=call_user_func_array(array($this->real, $method), $args);
        return $ret;
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        echo "isset $name\n";
    }
}
//-----Can't change below
$r=new decorator(1,2);
if (!method_exists($r,'test')) {die ("method 'test' does not exist, Fail :(\n");}
echo $r->test();
```

Any ideas ? (I'm thinking of generating a wrapper class by eval())

Comment: I made eval() wrapper, but hope on better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is extremely simple:

**Make the decorator class extend the real class**

```
<?php
class real {
    function __construct() {
        var_dump( func_get_args());
    }
    protected function test(){
        echo "test output\n";
    }
}
class decorator extends real{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct( func_get_args());
    }

    function __call($method,$args){
        echo "called $method\n";
        return call_user_func_array( array( 'parent', $method), $args);
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        echo "isset $name\n";
    }
}
//-----Can't change below
$r = new decorator(1,2);
if(!method_exists($r,'test')) {die ("method 'test' does not exist, Fail :(\n");}
echo $r->test();
```

This is a much better design, and [it works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G2IFdQ)!

To better solve the underlying problem of inspecting a proprietary encoded program, I also suggest the use of [XDebug's execution_trace](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace).

Comment: function __call(), will not be called on each calls,

Comment: It will be called on every non-public member function of `real` and `decorator`.

Comment: yes, looks like, btw in your  sample arguments not passed correct,

Comment: @eicto - I'm not sure what you're trying to do so I guessed - Tell me how the arguments need to be passed and I can fix it `:)` I updated my answer with what I believe to be the error!

Comment: working for method_exists, http://codepad.viper-7.com/94U7Yc
any idea of cheating 
*get_class_methods()* and *get_class_vars()* ?

Comment: also I found that they sometime call some methods as static.

Comment: @eicto - What do you need to do with `get_class_methods()` and `get_class_vars()`? Also, there's no way to intercept static methods (because of the definition of a static function).

Comment: May be better to write extention for php ? or may be there already one ?

Comment: My other comments:
The source that calls method_exist in proprietary encoded software(poorly documented), I need to intercept all it's calls to module class and log it, to understand more in logic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5731/discussion-between-nickb-and-eicto)

Comment: They checking presense of functions with method_exists() and get_class_methods(), also they call functions like decorator::test() I not sure that php allows to intercept all of that. I tried with class genereation by eval('clas {..}'), but it also not works as needed. I think your solution is best for now, I just still hope that there more universal solution for wrapping classes.

Answer (score 1):

First, __construct never return.

Second, to be a good/real decorator pattern, `decorator` class must decorate `real` object or another `real` extended object, so you should not instantiate the object within the construct method. A decorator pattern example will help you understand:

```
$coffee = new Coffee();
$coffe_extra_sugar = new Sugar($coffee); // Here you put more sugar
$coffe_extra_extra_sugar = new Sugar($coffe_extra_sugar); // Here you put more sugar!

class NewCoffe extends Coffee{} // Now a new coffee

$ncoffe = new NewCoffe();
$ncoffe_extra_sugar = new Sugar($ncoffe); // Good Decorator!
```

Third, you can create a method inside the `real` class who check if method exists:

```
public function method_exists($method){
    return method_exists($this,$method);
}
```

and create it on decorator too (dont forget to check into the real object):

```
public function method_exists($method){
    return method_exists($this,$method) || $this->real->method_exists($method);
}
```

Now think with me, if all your decorators extends from a unique Coffee decorator, you don't need to define this method into each decorator, so in my coffe example:

```
class CoffeeDecorator {

    protected $real;

    public function __construct($decorated_class){
        $this->real = $decorated_class;
    }

    public function method_exists($method){
        return method_exists($this,$method) || $this->real->method_exists($method);
    }

    function __call($method,$args){
            echo "called $method\n";
            $ret=call_user_func_array(array($this->real, $method), $args);
            return $ret;
    }

}

// Now create some coffe decorators
class Sugar extends CoffeeDecorator{
    // Methods for sugar decorator
}
```

Comment: but if code call function that defined in real method the __call() will not be executed, the real task is to wrap module for proprietary software to debug calls that software does on module. Also why class_method_exist() will call CoffeDecorator->method_exists() ? It is documented somewhere ?

Comment: The __call will be executed only for the methods who are not declared into the decorator (sugar) class, all proprietary methods from real class will be called... in your `if (!method_exists($r,'test'))` you must change to `if (!$r->method_exists('test'))`...

Comment: I know when __call() executed, as I placed in code - we can't change function that calls class_method_exists()

Comment: if you can't change, you will need to write these again and pass to the real class with `call_user_func_array` =/

Comment: seems I have to extend real class and generate functions with 
call_user_func_array to parent::

Answer (score 0):

The signature of [`__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) is `void __construct ([ mixed $args [, $... ]] )`.

In other words, `__construct()` only returns an instance of the object.

I think you are confusing yourself between [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use [override_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php)

Compile PHP with [apd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apd.installation.php),
once you have this ready,
you can easily override the built-in function method_exist to is_callable

<strike>Simply change the method_exist to [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) :-</strike>

```
$methodVariable = array($r, 'test');
var_dump(is_callable($methodVariable, true, $callable_name));
echo $callable_name, "\n";
```

Output :-

```
bool(true)
decorator::test
```

**What is is_callable?**

> Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function. This can check that a simple variable contains the name of a valid function, or that an array contains a properly encoded object and function name.

To add, method_exist is just checking,
in your case, the method is **NEVER** actually declare,
whilst is_callable checking the method can be called,
with __call, this is return true.

Comment: The source that calls method_exist in proprietary encoded software(poorly documented), I need to intercept all it's calls to module class and log it, to understand more in logic, so I can't change method_exists() to other funcitons.

Comment: sorry, poor understanding. In short, **NO**, I think you trying to catch all the dynamic calls to any method? But `__call` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context. So, is like chicken or egg problem. The rest of the answers suggesting to hard-code all sort of method, which I dun think what you really after for.